# Need to run check the click event only once with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code which is checking the click event but I need to run that only once and after that, it should be removed or disabled.
Can anyone help?

```
  $.each(posts, function(reaction, amount) {
        self.reactions[reaction] = amount
        if (Cookies.get('rns_reacted_' + reaction + '_' + self.id)) {
          self.clickedReactions.push(reaction);
        }
      });`
```

Comment: have a look at jQuery one: http://api.jquery.com/one/ this is basically exactly what you're asking for

Comment: Hi I have used .one but i think i am not able to add that properly . As http://amagesoft.com/booking/2017/01/11/liberty-party-2/  in this url i need to select only one reaction in one session but right now its selecting multiple. A clicked class is applied which is increasing this .

Comment: oh I see. in that case you may have to store in a variable that the user already clicked. Then on the click handler, check if the variable is set. If yes, just do nothing, otherwise do your click handler stuff

Answer (score 0):

So how using on and off, coupled with [name spaced click events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)?

```
$(".container").on("click.only-once", ".clickables", function() {
    // ... treat the click event here
    $(".container").off("click.only-once", ".clickables"); // remove our click handler so it never fires again (until the page reloads...)
});
```

Hope this helps!